# Can't display data in localhost browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I creating an app that stores data but when i finish the prompt input i get this error:
 [image: error screenshot]

Here is my CptList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import uuid from 'uuid';



export default class CpdList extends Component{
    state = {}
    handleClick = () => {
      const date = prompt('Enter Date')
      const activity = prompt('Enter Activity')
      const hours = prompt('Enter Hours')
      const learningStatement = prompt('Enter Learning Statement')
      const evidence = prompt('YES! or NO!')
      this.setState(state => ({
        items: [
          ...state.items,
          {
            id: uuid(),
            date,
            activity,
            hours,
            learningStatement,
            evidence
          }
        ]
      }));
    }

    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;

        return (
            <Container>
                <Button
                    color='dark'
                    style={{marginBottom: '2rem'}}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                >Add Data</Button>

                <Button
                    color='dark'
                    style={{marginBottom: '2rem'}}
                    onClick={() => { this.handleClick(items._id) }}
                >Delete Data</Button>
            </Container>
        );
    };
};
```

Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong? I am also having trouble with my delete function, this is my delete coding in my backend:

```
//Delete a Item
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Item.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(item => item.remove().then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});
```

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(state.items);`?

Comment: Use the following mongoose query :-
Item.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        else
            res.json({ message: 'Item Deleted!'});
    });

Comment: @MEDZ i just see: Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to initialize state with:

```
state = { items:[] }
```

The first time you add item to undefined empty list.

Moreover I think missing a state.items.map somewhere (at least for delete button)

Comment: ok i think my delete button works now but the data is still not displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
state = [] // convert to array beacuse use map() or other javascipt method

 this.setState(state => ({
            items: [
// do not speard maybe 
              {
                id: uuid(),
                date,
                activity,
                hours,
                learningStatement,
                evidence
              }
            ]
          }));
```

plz write handleClick function 
tell me working or not